# two simple questions about purely atomic probability space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

1. Is that a probability space with every random variable(real valued) integral must be purely atomic? How about the inverse statement?
2. Is there any non-countable purely atomic probability space?

Comment: Do you mean integral?  There is no convergent sum of uncountably many positive terms...just use the pigeonhole principle to show that there must be some positive integer $n$ with infinitely many of your terms between $\frac 1{n+1}$ and $\frac 1{n}$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I know how to prove the first statement.